# The most efficient way to solve $2^{2017} \mod 9$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, computational-algebra

I have just started my Computational Algebra course and I have to solve this relatively easy problem:
$$2^{2017} \mod 9$$
The first thing that I noticed was that $2$ and $9$ are coprime, therefore, I can use the Euler theorem to conclude that: (Congruence in terms of $\mod 9$ 
$$2^{\varphi(9)} \equiv 1$$
I calculate $\varphi(9)$ manually and get $6$, therefore
$$2^6 \equiv1$$
Notice that $2^{2017} = (2^6)^{336} \cdot 2$ and so
$$2^{2017} \mod 9 = (2^6)^{336} \cdot 2 \mod 9 = \\
= (2  \mod 9)(\mod9) = 2$$ 
However, I am pretty sure that there exists an easier way to solve this without resorting to such sophisticated theorems. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing particularly sophisticated in what you did! It hardly requires a theorem to note that $2^3=-1\bmod9$ and hence $2^6=1\bmod9$. Similarly, negligible theory is required to note that $2017=1\bmod6$ and so $2^{2017}=2\bmod9$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $2^3\equiv-1\pmod9$, $2^6\equiv1\pmod9$. But $2\,017\equiv1\pmod6$. Therefore, $2^{2\,017}\equiv2\pmod9$.

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{2017}=(3-1)^{2017}$$

Everything is divisible by $9$, when expanding, except the last two terms, which add up to $3\cdot 2017-1=672\cdot 9+2$. So: $$2^{2017}\equiv_9 2$$

Answer (score 1):

$2^3=8\equiv-1$ mod $9$ and $2017=1+3\cdot672$, so

$$2^{2017}=2\cdot(2^3)^{672}\equiv2(-1)^{672}=2\mod 9$$

Comment: Ah, I see this is almost exactly what José Carlos Santos said!

Answer (score 1):

By successive doublings modulo $9$, $$2^6\bmod9= 1.$$

Then $$2^{2017}\bmod9=2^{2017\bmod 6}=2^1.$$

Comment: How can one be sure that this sequence will hold for all numbers?

Comment: @Aemilius: $a\cdot 2^6\equiv a\cdot1$. This should convince you.

Comment: Reading this by itself, I'm not convinced that the next number after "5" is "1".  Perhaps that should be pointed out.  "The sequence is 1,2,4,8,7,5,1,2,4, ... so periodic with a period of 6".

Comment: @fleablood: reading this, I am not convinced that the period counts six elements.

Comment: It takes 6 iterations to get from 1, back to 1.  And once you get back to one everything else will have to repeat exactly as it had before.  (Although I feel a little weird going from something sophisticated and effiecient such as Euler's theorem to something basic like brute force.)

Comment: @Aemilius: I have reformulated, hopefully making it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You use the words "sophisticated" and "efficient".

I believe those to be contradictory.

$2^{2017}\equiv 2^{2017 \mod \phi(9)= 6} \equiv 2^{2017\equiv 1 \mod 6} \equiv 2^1 = 2 \mod 9$.

is VERY efficient and is the *most* efficient way you can do this.

But you complain it is too "sophisticated".  Why is that a problem?  Okay, it violates the "explain it to my like I was 5" concept.

Okay, there are less sophisticated ways.  But they are *less* efficient.

And the *easiest* way is brute force:

$1,2,2^2,2^3,.... etc.$ will eventually have to repeat.  So we have to find out when it repeats.  It we do that by punching.  As there are only $9$ possible values the $2^k$ can be equivalent to, we can rest in knowing we'll only have to punch at most nine times.

$1 ,2, 2^2, 2^3 ,.... \equiv 1,2,4,8,16 \equiv 7, 32\equiv 5, 64 \equiv 1$.  That's it.  It repeats every $6$ times.

(We could have more *efficient*ly  noticed we don't need to do $2*16=32\equiv 5$ but $2*7=14 \equiv 5$ and $2*5=1 \equiv 1$ rather than $2*32 = 64 \equiv 1$.  But that would have required *sophistication*.)

So $2^{2017 = 1 + 6*k} \equiv 2^1 \equiv 1 \mod 9$.

That was *very* easy.  But not very efficient.

Perhaps the best compromise is to note that $2^3 =8\equiv -1 \mod 9$ so $2^6\equiv 1 \mod 9$ and take it from there.

But that requires *insight* and insight is not something that can be taught.

So your three options:

"sophistication":  You have a theorem that tells you how to do this *explicitely* and directly.  Can't get any more efficient than that.

"simplicity":  You can just do it by brute force.  Can't get any easier or *less* efficient than that.

"insight":  Works if you've got it.  (Sucks if you don't.)

Which of those three work the *best* will be a matter of taste, experience, and style.

==== old answer ===

Depends on what you call "efficient".

$\gcd(2,9)=1$ and $\phi(9) = 6$ so $2^6\equiv 1 \mod 9$ by Eulers theorem so $2^{2017} \equiv 2^{2017\mod 6}\equiv 2^1 \equiv 2 \mod 9$.

But is that efficient?  It is if you are comfortable with Euler's theorem.

Or $2^3 = 8\equiv -1 \mod 9$ so $2^{2017} = 2^{2016}*2 \equiv (2^3)^{someevennumber}*2 \equiv (-1)^{someevennumber}*2 \equiv 1*2 \equiv 2 \mod 9$.  Which is straightfoward brute force.

Or $2^3 = 8 \equiv 1$ so $2^6 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \mod 9$.  So $2^{2017} = 2^{2016}*2 = (2^6)^{somenumber}*2 \equiv 2 \mod 9$.

And if you didn't notice that $2^3 \equiv -1$?.... Then list out $2^0, 2^1, 2^2, ... \mod 9$ and see if there is a pattern.

$1,2,4, 8, 16\equiv 7, 14\equiv 5, 10\equiv 1, ... $ and from there it repeats.  So $2^6 \equiv 1$ and $2^{a+6} \equiv 2^a$.  So $2^{2017= 6*k + 1} \equiv 2^1 \equiv 1 \mod 9$.

Comment: This is the method that the OP used.

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Comment: Hem, followed by the one I used...

Comment: Im changing my post.  This seems to be more of an editorial subjective question of best method.  I favor "sophistication" and efficiency over simple, but both work.